# Javafx : Dialog pane reference

Tags: java, javafx, reflection, javafx-8, alert

I have a controller, which contains buttons, if I press one button an `Alert` shows, with Yes and No options, and I want to write a test for this controller class testing the result of this `Alert`, for example if I press the Yes button what happens. I could get the Window/Stage, and the Scene, but how can I get the `Alert` from the controller which popped up. Is that the primaryStage or I don't really understand how can I get it. I had a look at the hierarchy of the `Alert` and it doesn't have any relation with the `Stage` or `Scene` or just I didn't observed it. Is there a possibility to get a reference of the `Alert` or of its buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
Alert alert = new     Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");

alert.setHeaderText("Look, a     Confirmation Dialog");
alert.setContentText("Are you ok with   this?");

Optional<ButtonType> result =     alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
// ... user chose OK
} else {
// ... user chose CANCEL or closed    the dialog
}
```

This code above does what you need.

[Look here for more](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

And you can always consult java docs.

Comment: No this code is not for me, I think you didn't read attentively the question, I want to get the reference of an `Alert` from my controller using reflection.

Comment: Lets say you have :  Alert alert = new     Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);   accessing dialog pane can be achieved with :DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();... i hope that helps little bit, since i dont quite get your question.

Comment: I have class A, in that class i have methodA() which shows my `Alert`, by pressing a button, so I press the button using reflection so, my `Alert` pops up virtually even if I don't see, so I want to get a reference to that pane,window, whatever is that.